# Rails : facebook open graph

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am creating first story in facebook graph on my rails app. I have created a story for product upload.

SO when user creates products, story gets published on his timeline saying "User created a new product to sell. Check it out."

I got the code for object from facebook. But I am not getting where to write this code in my app. Should it be on product upload file which is new_product.html.erb or should i create new file in product folder?

If i create a new file, how to load it when new product gets created as my new_product.html.erb file calls show_product.file on product upload. SO how to set two actions on creation of product?

I am totally new to rails and facebook graph. Can somebody help here?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work follow working with this.

For publishing your story you need to write custom code on your view file meta tag. you have to send post request with product url. Here is an exaple: Suppose your product in on http://yoursite.com/product/124. and some one comments on your product. you have to do the following things for publish story for this product.

Create an action called for comment for object product from your app dashboard.
write meta tag on view (like show.html.erb) head as

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="yoursite.com">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
<meta property="og:type" content="namespace:product">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://yoursite.com/product/124">
<meta property="og:title" content="Product name">
<meta property="og:description" content="description">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://yoursite.com/product/124.jpg">
```

3.Finally make a post request when comment on that product, you can use Koala easily to post this.

@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_access_token)

```
@graph.put_connections("me", "namespace:comment", :product => "http://yoursite.com/product/124", :message => "Send your message here.")
```